# Maximum of a linear function in a set that is convex but not compact

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, maxima-minima

Let $f: V\to \mathbb{R}$ be a linear function defined on some real vector space $V$.

It is known that, if $U$ is a convex and compact subset of $V$, then $f$ attains its maximum at some extreme point of $U$.

Suppose $U$ is a convex subset of $V$, but not necessarily compact. 
In this case, it is possible that $f$ does not attain its maximum in $V$.
What can be said about the maximum point of $f$ in this case? Is it true that $f$ attains its maximum in a boundary point of $V$?

Comment: @MeesdeVries OP is considering linear functions.

Answer (score 0):

If $U$ is not compact, either its closure $\bar U$ is bounded, then it is compact and convex (in which case you are right and the maximum will be attained on the boundary if it is not attained in the interior) or $\bar U$ is unbounded. In the latter case it is possible that there is no maximum at all, for example for $f(x)=x$ and $U=\mathbb{R}=V$.

Comment: What does it mean for a subset of a general vector space to be "bounded" - is it bounded in this sense https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set_(topological_vector_space) ?

Comment: Oh, I didn't pay enough attention. I was thinking of finite dimensional vector spaces only.